# Using pacf function on a dataframe with .apply()

Tags: python, statsmodels

Problem: I have a dataframe with customer id and their spending over time.

I would like to get the `pacf` for each of the customers and take the mean and max to understand whether a customer is seasonal or not.

I am using the `.apply()` method on the dataframe as such:

```py
raw_data.groupby('merchant')['amount_usd'].apply(lambda x: np.max(sm.tsa.stattools.pacf(x)))
```

Yhis is leading to the following error:

> LinAlgError: Singular matrix

Does anyone know how to deal with this?

Thank you!